# Heading from product filter

Tags: bigcartel

I'm using the Foundry theme and on the `/products` page. I have links to the different categories of products. These take you to `/category/______`. There is a `<h1>` heading, which has a default of value `Shop`. I want the value to represent the current category. I tried the following code, but the heading was just blank.

```
<h1>
...
{% elsif page.full_url contains "category/" %}
    {% for category in categories.all %}
      {% if page.full_url contains {{ category.permalink }} %}{{ category.name }}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
...
</h1>
```

Examples:

- `page.full_url` returns `https://website/category/wall-hangings`
- `category.permalink` returns `wall-hangings`

I also tried a method using:

```
{{ page.full_url | remove: "https://website/category" | replace: "-" " " | capitalize }}
```

However, the `replace` method doesn't insert spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I overcomplicated my original approach. Using `{{ page.name }}` returns the category name, so using this in the heading tag worked.